# Convert string::iterator to std::string

Tags: c++, string, iterator, type-conversion

Now this is a little confusing for me, but std::string::iterator actually yields a char (as revealed by typeid). I need it as a string though. How can I do this?

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    for( std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++ ){
        std::string expectsString(*it); // error
        std::string expectsString(""+*it); // not expected result
        myFunction(expectsString);
    }
}
```

I'm using gcc 5.4.0 with C++11 enabled.

edit: As this needs further clarification
I want to convert *it to a string. So I can use the currently iterated through character as a string, instead of a char.
As my failed examples in the above code example demonstrate, I was looking for something like

```
std::string myStr = *it; //error
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. The for-loop iterates through a single string. What output do you want? "Hello World", "ello World", "llo World", etc.?

Comment: I need to convert the iterator to a string as myFunction expects a string as parameter.

Comment: I don't want any output. I just want the conversion of *it to a string.

Comment: This is just an easy example program which has only some resemblance to my actual program

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to me and the problem I'm currently working on.

Comment: It is not easy to understand what you want or expect. Read up: [MCVE]

Comment: What does it mean to you to "convert a pointer to a character to a string"?

Comment: Please clarify what your intent is. A std::string iterator is similar to a char pointer with C strings. Do you want to convert the pointed-to character to a string, or the substring from the pointed-to character to the end?

Comment: I hope my intent is clear now for everybody (see updated post)

Comment: You just wanted to print the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead

```
std::string expectsString(1, *it);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string str = "Hello World!";

    for( std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++ )
    {
        std::string expectsString( 1, *it );
        std::cout << expectsString;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: That doesn't call myFunction with expectsString in a loop. If all he wanted to do was to print the string, why use a for-loop?

Comment: @JiveDadson The program just demonstrates using of the appropriate constructor.

Comment: I can easily replace std::cout << expectsString with myFunction(expectsString). I accepted this answer, as it was the earlierst and most elaborated, as I had to chose from all three correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string expectsString{ *it };
```

Answer (score 3):

Could also construct string of length 1 from `it` using range constructor

`std::string expectsString(it, it+1);`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternatives:

```
std::string expectsString{*it};   // Use initializer_list<char>
std::string expectsString({*it}); // Use initializer_list<char>
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964885d4da61cdae)

Comment: This doesnt compile

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: link added, it compiles fine.

Comment: @jaraod42 Strange ..I am using VC++ for compilation and it gives me error
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the string and later can use that for storing *it to that string and can use, which you can use as string anywhere.

```
std::string el;

 list <std::string> :: iterator it;

 for(it = variableOrder.begin(); it != variableOrder.end(); it++){
                el = *it;
            
                cout << el << endl;
            }
```

Comment: What is variable order?

Comment: @infinitezero variable order is same as the order in which elements are inserted in the list.